# Change GUI after child thread is finished - QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a question about QT thread. In my application GUI I want to add image to window, and after some time (when child thread will finish his work and will be closed) I want to remove this image.
How in this situation inform main thread that child thread finished his works?
I red some QT documentation, but didn't help:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html
If it is needed, I will add some code.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you also read the documentation for `QThread`?

Comment: You need to get to know one concept, signals and slots in Qt, and one signal, the `finished()` signal of QThread. This will be enough for your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to connect signal `finished()` of `QThread` to slot, which will remove your image.

Little example:

```
QObject::connect(your_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), your_class, SLOT(your_slot()));

class YourClass
{
/* ... */

public slots:
    void your_slot() { /* remove image */ }

/* ... */
};
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you very much. I didn't know that I can pass thread object to connect function :)

Comment: Actually you can pass object of any class which inherits from QObject